# correct webpack config for babel 6, react hot load, webpack middleware

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-hot-middleware

Having read a novel's worth of SO posts on webpack configurations I still can't get past the `module parse failed` error.

**package.json (not all of it)**

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.6",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015-webpack": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
}
```

**structure**

```
package.json
node_modules
.babelrc
client/
    webpack.config.js
    .babelrc         # duplicated just for shits and giggles...
    src/
        index.jsx
        components/
server/
    index.js
    //more stuff
```

**client/webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  context: __dirname + '/src',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    __dirname + '/src/index.jsx'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:12345'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        include: __dirname + '/src',
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0'],
        query: { 
          plugins: ['./babelRelayPlugin'],
          presets: ['es2015', 'react'] 
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{ "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"] }
```

**client/src/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from './src/components/layout.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Been poking in the dark modifying the webpack config and can't babel to transpile es6.

**Recurring problems from other SO posts**

1. `Loaders` array has to be inside `module` property
2. Add `presets` array to your `.babelrc`
3. `npm install --save babel-preset-whatever`
4. `hot-loader` is depreciated, use [`babel-preset-react-hmre`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react-hmre)
5. Loaders are loaded from right to left, top to bottom

At a loss.

Comment: Seems like you have a trailing `,` in your `package.json`

Comment: copy and pasted incorrectly

Comment: Can you push your project to GitHub? Easier to see what's wrong. I have my notes about configuring Babel 6 [here](http://survivejs.com/webpack/advanced-techniques/configuring-react/). Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my `context` property was messing everything up, the errors were not that helpful though. Docs clearly state what `context` does, guess I wasn't paying attention to that carefully enough.

```
//webpack.config.js
context: __dirname + '/client/src/',
target: 'web'

//index.jsx

//this will break everything
import Layout from './src/components/Layout.jsx' 

//this will work
import Layout from './components/Layout.jsx'
```

I just switched that and everything works great now.

Answer (score 0):

[easy-react](https://github.com/asm-jaime/easy-react)

I created a small starter for myself. Just check my config, it worked for me.

Comment: On previous attempts I had gotten babel 6 working with webpack dev server, but now my config is broken when I try to use hot middleware with express, but thanks.